# "Blanket implementations" returning error in Rust

Tags: rust, traits

I made a Trait:

```
pub trait DimenBasics {
    // --snip--
    fn get_value(&self) -> f64;

    fn get_unit(&self) -> String;

    fn verified_add(&self, other: &Self) -> Result<Self, String>
    where
        Self: Sized;
    // --snip--
}
```

And I was trying to make a "blanket implementation", here is the code:

```
impl<D: DimenBasics> UpperExp for D {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "{:E}{}", self.get_value(), self.get_unit())
    }
}
```

I thought it was fine because, for me, it's similar to the example in rust docs:

```
impl<T: Display> ToString for T {
    // --snip--
}
```

But I got this error:

```
error[E0210]: type parameter `D` must be used as the type parameter for some local type (e.g., `MyStruct<D>`)
    --> dimension/src/lib.rs:1111:6
     |
1111 | impl<D: DimenBasics> UpperExp for D
     |      ^ type parameter `D` must be used as the type parameter for some local type
     |
     = note: implementing a foreign trait is only possible if at least one of the types for which it is implemented is local
     = note: only traits defined in the current crate can be implemented for a type parameter
```

What is causing this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message from the compiler seems pretty clear.  You aren't allowed to create blanket implementations for traits that are not defined in your own crate.  The example you give from the standard library works because both `ToString` and the blanket implementation are in the same crate.

This is disallowed because otherwise two crates could create such a blanket implementation and then they would conflict.  This would create situations where you can't use two crates together because they both decided to create a blanket implementation of the same external trait.  As more crates are uploaded and dependency graphs grow sufficiently complicated, the odds of this happening increase dramatically, and it would be an untenable situation.

Comment: So is there a alternative to this? Or I really need to implement separately for each struct?

Comment: Yes, you would have to implement separately. You can use a macro to hold the implementation so you don't have to repeat that for each struct. In other words, rather than copy-pasting the whole implementation, you'd just have something like `impl_upper_exp!(StructName)`.